# Build with libpq-fe.h on 64 bit windows with codeblocks, cannot start correctly

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

Haveing some troubles compiling and running a program with codeblocks, connecting postgresql, on windows 64 bit. Postgresql also 64 bit.

I already used **libpq-fe.h** under linux, on 64 or 32 bit without problem. Now, on windows I'm stuck.

I installed last version of code::blocks on the windows machine, and used GNU GCC compiler. Then started coding, everything fine, until I included libpq-fe.h.

So, 32 bit vs 64 bit fight (Libpq.dll: File not recognized), so I installed and configured it under codeblocks.

After some troubles with TIMESPEC finally it compiled. But does not start.

First error:

```
The program can't start because SSLEAY32.dll is missing from yout computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

To fix this I copied the dll from postgresql installation to exe path. Same problem the with **libeay32.dll**.

Now, when I start my exe I obtain:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.
```

I think coping dll this way is not a good thing. But... How can I solve this error? What to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the trick.
Installed Openssl for windows, the last 64 bit version found here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Now it runs fine.